# Unable to open and display an image file

Tags: python, image, pickle

I am trying to open a random image from a folder and display it using matplotlib inline.Following is what I did

```
fileObject = open("notMNIST_small/J.pickle",'rb') 
read_list = pickle.load(fileObject) 
random_image = np.random.choice (read_list)
%matplotlib inline
plt.imshow(random_image)
```

I get the below error. What am I doing wrong?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-a10f05254093> in <module>()
      1 fileObject = open("notMNIST_small/J.pickle",'rb')
      2 read_list = pickle.load(fileObject)
----> 3 random_image = np.random.choice (read_list)
      4 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
      5 plt.imshow(random_image)

  mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.choice     (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:15428)()

  ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface of numpy´s `random.choice` function has a second keyword argument called `size`. It specifies how many samples should be drawn from your data array. By default `size` is set to `None` in which case only one sample is drawn from your dataset.

In order to solve your problem define a variable `n` and initialize it with the number of values you need from `random.choice`.

```
n = 10    # for example
random_image = np.random.choice(read_list, n)
```

If you need all the values to be shuffled, I recommend to use `random.shuffle` instead. Simply replace the above lines by:

```
np.random.shuffle(read_list)
```

Note that `random.shuffle` has no return value. It operates in place, which means `read_list` will be changed.